# VBA userform created on Excel 2016 loses its controls when opened with Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

I created a VBA project using Excel 2016 on my workplace computer. To work on it at home, I saved it as a .xlsm file in a flash drive. My home computer uses Excel 365. The files open normally but when I try to launch one of my userforms through a commandbutton placed in one of the sheets, "Run-time error '424' Object required" appears. I found out that the userform controls are missing, but upon checking the same file on my workplace computer (Excel 2016), the controls are still there.

I tried tweaking the macros security settings to "enable all..", and the Trusted Locations settings to see if it will show the missing controls, but it did not work.

I'm completely lost on how to solve this. Need help, thanks!

Comment: Which controls are missing? All of them?

Comment: All of them except for the multipage control

Comment: What controls were they? Standard ones from the MSForms library?

Comment: Yes, the standard ones, specifically listed: (textbox, combobox, listbox, commandbutton)

Comment: Can you add them back on your home computer?

Comment: Yes, and I also tried testing these controls, and it works fine; however, I cant let go of the missing control problem because I might encounter it again.

Comment: Sounds like an incompatibility between versions of the FM20.dll file, though I've never heard of it affecting userform controls before. You could try closing all office apps, then searching your hard drive for any `.exd` files (these are temp files used by office) and deleting them, then search for `Excel.box` and `frmcache.dat` and delete those too, then try your file again. You can also rename them instead of deleting them if you prefer.

Comment: Did this, but the problem still persists. Thank you anyway!